# Customized inversion of a series of minutes in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, timedelta, python-datetime

I have a `pandas.Series` of strings that represent minutes in a countdown manner, which I would like to invert for having it in an increasing chronological manner. That is, Consider the following `Series`:

```
pd.Series([ '30:00', '25:10', '22:30' ])
Out[1]:
0    30:00
1    25:10
2    22:30
dtype: object
```

Thee series' terms are minutes:seconds. I want to invert it and obtain seconds as integer values. That is, the highest is '30:00', which I would like to be the starting point, getting the value of 0. For '25:10' I would like to have `5*60-10=290`. For '22:30' I want `7.5*60=450` and so on. Thus, I would like to obtain the following Series:

```
0    0
1    290
2    450
dtype: object
```

I know that the original series can be converted into datetime objects using `pd.to_datetime`. But am unsure how to invert it from countdown to increasing seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more general and pandas specific approach using [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
s = pd.to_timedelta('00:'+s).astype('timedelta64[s]')
s = s.iloc[0] - s
```

The resulting output:

```
0      0.0
1    290.0
2    450.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use apply() and a conversion function to do this:

**Code:**

```
def count_down_from_30(time_string):
    min, sec = [int(x) for x in time_string.split(':')]
    return 30 * 60 - 60 * min - sec
```

**Test:**

```
data = pd.Series(['30:00', '25:10', '22:30'])
data = data.apply(count_down_from_30)
print(data)
```

**Results:**

```
0      0
1    290
2    450
dtype: int64
```